# For in loop results sometimes in EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, swift, exc-bad-access

Sometimes I get a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error in this code:

```
internal func downloadMultiple(files: NSMutableArray, remoteBaseUrl: NSURL, completion: (result: Int)->()) -> Void {
    self.filesToDownload = files
    self.cb = completion

    for item in files { // this line gets marked, but why this line?
        print("file ", item["file"] as! String)
        self.download(remoteBaseUrl.URLByAppendingPathComponent(item["file"] as! String)!)
    }
}
```

But it occurs only sometimes, any idea how to figure out what is causing this?

Comment: `item["file"]` is nil?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the crash because `item[file]` is `nil` and you are using force unwrapping, go with optional binding like this

```
for item in files { 
    // this line gets marked, but why this line?
    if let file = item["file"] as String {
        print("file ", file)
        self.download(remoteBaseUrl.URLByAppendingPathComponent(file)
    } else {
        print("file not available")
    }

}
```

Comment: Think of the `!` force unwrap opererator as the "crash if nil" operator. That's what it does. If you are not 100% certain that the thing you are unwrapping can never be nil, don't use it.

Comment: In my theory it could never be nil, but this creates a reference: `self.filesToDownload = files` and i removed items from it as soon as they where downloaded and the `NSMutableArray ` can't have holes, thats why they got `nil`. Is my new theory :) but need to test it more.